# Simple soql breaking limits

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to update the account every time a contact is updated and the simplest thing seems to be blowing up.

```
trigger ContactAccountOriginTrigger on Contact (before insert, before Update) {
    List<Account> AccountList = new List<Account>();
    List<ID> IdList = new List<ID>();

    for (Integer i = 0; i <Trigger.new.size(); i++){
       IdList.Add(Trigger.new[i].AccountId);        
    }    

    AccountList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id in : IdList];

    for (Integer i = 0; i <Trigger.new.size(); i++){
        if (AccountList.size() > 0){
            for (Account a:AccountList){
                if(Trigger.new[i].Focus_ID__c != null || Trigger.new[i].Focus_ID__c == ''){             
                    logic
                }
                else{
                    logic
                }
                if(a.get('Id') == null) {
                    insert a;                   
                }else{
                    update a;
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class ContactAccountOriginTest {
    static testMethod void insertNewAccount() {
        Account acctToCreate = new Account();
        Contact contToCreate = new Contact();

        acctToCreate.Name  = 'Practice Test';
        insert acctToCreate;

        //1st pass
        contToCreate.FirstName = 'test';
        contToCreate.LastName = 'test';
        contToCreate.AccountId = acctToCreate.Id;
        contToCreate.Focus_ID__c = '00001';
        insert contToCreate;
        update acctToCreate;

        //2nd pass
        contToCreate.FirstName = 'test';
        contToCreate.LastName = 'test';
        contToCreate.AccountId = acctToCreate.Id;
        contToCreate.Focus_ID__c = null;
        update contToCreate; 

        update acctToCreate;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could tell u what the issue is. Would make it much much easier to help you. Include error messages verbatim. Immediately I see DML inside a for loop and some extraneous code

Comment: If you don't know if your record has an Id or not, you can use `upsert` to say to the database "hey, update this thing if it exists, or insert it otherwise". So you can eliminate that last condition when you check the Id.

Comment: Fyi, a field coming from the database will never be equal to '' (the empty string); it will either be null or contain at least one non-white-space character. Also, no need to check if a list is empty before you iterate over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to update the exsisting account of the contact if it has a Account else create a new Account. Below is an example of how you can update the parent based on the child:

Although, you may consider using a Process builder which can update the parent record or even create new records. Might save you writing some lines of code.

```
trigger ContactAccountOriginTrigger on Contact (before insert,before update) {


    List<ID> IdList = new List<ID>();
    List<Account> accToUpdateOrInsert = new List<Account>();
    for(Contact c : trigger.new){
        if(c.accountid!=Null){
        idList.add(c.accountid);   
        }else{
           Account a = new Account(Name='WhatName');
           accToUpdateOrInsert.add(a);
        }
    }

    Map<Id,Account> accountMap = new Map<Id,Account>();
    List<Account> accList = [select id,Name,(select id, Focus_ID__c from Contacts) from Account where id in:idList];
    For(Account a : accList){
      if(a.contacts.size()>0){
        For(Contact c: a.Contacts){
            accountMap.put(c.id,a);          
        }
      }

    }

    For(Contact c:trigger.new){

        if(c.Focus_ID__c!=NULL){       
        Account acnt = accountMap.get(c.id);
        // Your Logic to do whatever with the account field
        accToUpdateOrInsert.add(acnt);       
        }else{
        Account acnt = accountMap.get(c.id);
        // Your Logic to do whatever with the account field
        accToUpdateOrInsert.add(acnt); 
        }

    }

    upsert accToUpdateOrInsert;

}
```

Comment: I like the thought of the process builder, granted I tried it and since our people are deciding not to assign primary contacts that's kinda dead, right?

I'm getting another error when I try to deploy:
Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.ContactAccountOriginTrigger: line 29, column 1

The logic is update some info, just a field for now, to a text string. The field is a picklist with set values.

ex. acnt.Account_Origin__c = 'test';

I feel like an idiot. This seems so simple. my .net mind not working with this.

Comment: Does your pick list value has restricted values?

Comment: Did you say you got null pointer when you try to deploy? or update a particular contact with a Account associated with it. Null pointer can't occur because the loop runs for contact with account data.

Comment: Nope, no restricted values. 

Yes. it fails to validate when deploying. I see what you mean, but that's the error, which is why I'm a bit confused too.

Comment: Bit of a duh moment, I forgot one of fields.

Thanks for the help, I need to get in the habit of using maps instead of relying on lists.

Comment: I see. Glad to help!

Comment: In this case, you can assign to a lookup field directly - use the `Map<ID, sObject>` constructor on your SOQL query result, then loop through contacts and assign with `for(Contact c : Trigger.New){c.Account = accnMap.get(c.AccountID);}`

Comment: Why do you have to do `for(Contact c : Trigger.New){c.Account = accnMap.get(c.AccountID);} ` ? Can  you let me know? OP wants to update a field on Account object.

Comment: @SfdcBat Oh, you're right, I thought he was updating the Contact.  You could still use the `Map<ID, Account>` constructor and use `c.AccountID` rather than creating a new map associating the contactID to accounts.

Comment: I want to store id of the contact as the key and not accountId.